# With iOS how to get JSON from website and save as it is?

Tags: ios, json, xcode

I've been trying to figure out how to get the content of a JSON file, from a website, and then save that content - the actual { ... } object to a file in iOS (with XCode).  Being new to iOS, I figured I would look online but nothing seems to be applicable.  How do I actually get the JSON file content itself and not the byte size of the content?

**Here is how the call is setup:**

```
func test() {
    let url = NSURL(string: "https://www.somesite.com/file.json")
    let request = NSURLRequest(url: url! as URL)
    let session = URLSession.shared
    var json: Any
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { data, response, error -> Void in
        if let data = data {
            **[PROBLEM APPEARS TO BE HERE]** json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options[])
            let dataToSave = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json, options:[])
            print(dataToSave)
        }
    })
    task.resume()
}
```

I've also tried something like *NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)* but that creates an escaped string of the content that, when saved to a file, is unrecognized by the native JSON decoder when it reads the file.

Comment: You have data, you try to convert it to object, and then you try to convert it back to data. Why are you doing that? If your url request returns JSON, just store the data as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I've only dipped into **iOS** and **XCode 11.5** for a couple of weeks now, I appear to have the answer to the question specified above.  In short, the behavior of disk based reading and writing of JSON varies significantly from attempting to do the same thing with a asynchronous web request and requires attaching a "helper" function to complete saving website JSON content to the local disk.

**BASE FUNCTION MAKING WEB REQUEST:**

```
func test1() {
    var targetUrl = NSURL(string: "https://www.somesite.com/file.json")
    let request = NSURLRequest(url: targetUrl! as URL)
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { data, response, error -> Void in
        if let data = data {
            /* To avoid errors about "Invalid conversion from throwing function of type '(Data?,URLResponse?,Error?) throws -> Void' to non-throwing function type '(Data?,URLResponse?,Error?) -> Void'", when attempting to manipulate data here, pass data containing the file content to a helper function. */
            self.test2Helper(contentData: data.self)
        }
    })
    task.resume()
    return
}
```

**HELPER FUNCTION TO SAVE THE JSON CONTENT FROM THE WEBSITE:**

```
func test2Helper(contentData: Data) {
    /* Retrieve filepath information for app's Documents folder on device */
    let appDocumentsFolder = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
    let fullPath = appDocumentsFolder.appendingPathComponent("website").appendingPathExtension("json")
    /* For manually opening the file for verification, show the path */
    print(fullPath)
    /* Save the JSON content to the file */
    do {
        /* Build JSON Data Object */
        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: contentData)
        /* Save JSON Data to Documents */
        let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json, options: [])
        try data.write(to: fullPath, options: [])
        /* For testing, show completion */
        print("JSON content from website saved to disk.")
    }
    catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: Same comment again: Converting data to JSON and back to data serves no useful purpose whatsoever.